# How to get values from a DataFrame depending on a predefiend row & column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames in python, where I'm trying to return the values in `df` based on the date and column name, the real DataFrame is very long so this must be done using some kind of loop

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Avg1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Avg2': [3, 5, 1, 15],
    'Date': ['2021-08-06', '2021-08-07', '2021-08-08', '2021-08-07']
})
```

|  | Avg1 | Avg2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | 2021-08-06 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 2021-08-07 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 2021-08-08 |
| 3 | 4 | 15 | 2021-08-07 |

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Return Avg': ['Avg1', 'Avg2'],
    'At Date': ['2021-08-08', '2021-08-07'],
    'Returned values (what I want)': [3, 5]
})
```

|  | Return Avg | At Date | Returned values (what I want) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Avg1 | 2021-08-08 | 3 |
| 1 | Avg2 | 2021-08-07 | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) is what you are looking for.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Avg1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Avg2': [3, 5, 1, 15],
    'Date': ['2021-08-06', '2021-08-07', '2021-08-08', '2021-08-07']
})
```

then :

```
df.melt(id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['Avg1', 'Avg2'])

         Date variable  value
0  2021-08-06     Avg1      1
1  2021-08-07     Avg1      2
2  2021-08-08     Avg1      3
3  2021-08-07     Avg1      4
4  2021-08-06     Avg2      3
5  2021-08-07     Avg2      5
6  2021-08-08     Avg2      1
7  2021-08-07     Avg2     15
```

Comment: That seems correct but  the real dataframe is quite large so I'm unsure as to how I would loop from AVG1 to AVGn(value_vars) using melt

Comment: Got it to work by just using df.melt(id_vars=['Date']) , thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

let's start with a function

```
table1 = pd.DataFrame({'Avg1':[1,2,3,4],'Avg2':[3,5,1,15],'Date':['2021-08-06','2021-08-07','2021-08-08','2021-08-09']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Return Avg':['Avg1','Avg2'],'At Date':['2021-08-08','2021-08-07']})    

def get_the_currect_value(date, col_name, ext_table):
        return ext_table.loc[ext_table['Date'] == date, col_name].iloc[0]
```

now after the function, we will use apply to create the new column you want

```
df2['rv'] = df2.apply(lambda x: get_the_currect_value(x['At Date'],x['Return Avg'], table1),axis=1)
```

and that it